# Send data about charging between broadcast and activity with Shared Preferences [android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I'm using `BroadcastReceiver` to send information about status of battery charging to my Main Activity. App uses `SharedPreferences` to send data.

The problem is when my phone is connected or disconnected to charge. The app is crashed. I think this is problem with `SharedPreferences`. Am i right? And what i should do to get in working well?

This is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        SharedPreferences pref;

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 


            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = pref.edit();

                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);         
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

                prefEditor.putBoolean("isCharging", false).commit();

                int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

                boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        }
}
```

And this is Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pref = getSharedPreferences("StatusOfCharging", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isCharging = pref.getBoolean("isCharging", false);
        if (isCharging == true){
            Toast.makeText(this, "work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Don't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please post your Logcat..

Comment: Replace `pref = getSharedPreferences("StatusOfCharging", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);` to `pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("install_code_prefs",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: @Lal It's a problem because i'm running application on my device and if i discconect it, Logcat don't see it then. That's why i can't check it.

Comment: Why you need to disconnect to check the Logcat??? initialise pref in `BroadcastReceiver` too

Comment: pref is null in your broadcast receiver!

Comment: @Lal Because application work properly until I disconnect or connect in charge my device. Then there is a problem and app is crashed.

Comment: @user2944616 So how can i set it properly?

Comment: Check the answer for that @rewarien ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise `pref` like

```
pref = context.getSharedPreferences("StatusOfCharging",context.MODE_‌​PRIVATE);
```

in your `BroadcastReceiver` inside `onReceive()`..

Comment: I get this:
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type PowerConnectionReceiver.

I think the broadcast class haven't this method.